# Is Leaflet Framework free?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, mapbox, license

Is Leaflet 100% free?

if you  go to doc example , you will see :

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Which means that the tiles are supplied by mapbox.

Comment: *Which means that **in this example** the tiles are supplied by Mapbox.

Answer (score 15):

Leaflet is free ($) and open, with a minimal requirement of keeping the [license](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/LICENSE) should you redistribute it.

Leaflet is a library that lets you display - and more - data. It is **not** a data provider.

Mapbox, OSM and others are data providers/distributors and have their own restrictions / attribution requirements.

So to answer your question, yes, Leaflet is free. Mapbox describe their free/paid offers [here](https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/).

Comment: To add to this answer; You are not obligated to use MapBox layers in a Leaflet Map. you can use any provider or make your own which follow the XYZ standard. Here is a plugin which shows how you can add a wide variety of layers: https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

Comment: As [Devdatta Tengshe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/442/devdatta-tengshe) has mentioned before, Leaflet uses so called the de facto XYZ Standard, which obeys following scheme: 'http://{s}.somedomain.com/blabla/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png'. [Mostafa](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/123762/mostafa), you can find more information in [Leaflet documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#tilelayer).